# How to add two TextView one after the other in a ListView?

Tags: android, listview, textview, listadapter

I am creating a ListView dynamically and want to add two TextViews in a single ListItem (one Below the other). If I add both TextView they are overlapping each other (The reason I m adding two TextView is because both have to have different text size and styles.)

here is the code... inside the custom ListAdapter getView Method

```
FrameLayout v = new FrameLayout(AppStarter.this);
TextView title = new TextView(AppStarter.this);
TextView date = new TextView(AppStarter.this);
title.setTextSize(16);
title.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
title.setText(values[position]);
date.setText("Date : " + AppStarter.this.date[position]);
date.setTextSize(14);
v.addView(title);
v.addView(date, 1);
return v;
```

both title and date are overlapping each other I even tried `addView(date,1);`it didnt workout.

Comment: Why don't you just define your custom list item in an XML layout file and pass that to your list adapter?

Comment: @MisterSquonk: Its has to be a dynamic one because the data for the list is coming from a webservice...

Comment: who ever gave down vote could you explain the reason .. so that I can correct my mistake next time ...

Comment: @Arun: The point of an `AdapterView` (such as a `ListView`) is that the adapter is responsible for binding the data to the various view's components. If we all had to dynamically create out list items just because data that we're working with is dynamic then there'd be no point in using adapters. Android already provides a two `TextView` list item in `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2`. As for whoever voted your question down it's probably because using that list item view is very basic Android and can be found in many examples. Creating custom list views and adapters is also quite simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use LinearLayout or RelativeLayout.

```
    LinearLayout linear = new LinearLayout(this);
    linear.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
    tv1.setText("First Text!");
    TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
    tv2.setText("Second Text!");
    linear.addView(tv1);
    linear.addView(tv2);
```

pass the layout in adapter of listview.
or Add RelativeLayout and place views relatively on same

Comment: I have tried LinearLayout as well but it adds the date to the right of title which goes off the screen....

Comment: when u r using linearlayout and u have given the orientation as vertical i dont know why it goes on left side,if u copy paste my code it comes exactly below of the first text

Comment: Thank you sooooooooooooooo much you are awesome :) it worked i didn't set the orientation to vertical thats what my problem is anyway thanks man :)

Answer (score 1):

you have to make a xml file containing your desired design of listview and after that you have to pass that xml file to adapter and then adapter in listview like mentioned below

```
    private ListView listView;

    private myadapter myadapter;
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.BuddiesList);
    myadapter = new myadapter(this, R.id.XMLFILE, SourceOfdata);
    listView.setAdapter(myadapter);
```

Comment: I am not putting this list in a xml file it is a dynamically created Layout.... statically creating a ListView is not a big deal I can do that ..

Answer (score 1):

you will use this in program

addcategory1("title   ");

addcategory2(" date ");

Answer (score 0):

you will use this in program

addcategory1("   ");

addcategory2("  ");